# Jenkins master locks me out everytime I re-start the server

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, ldap

[image]My Jenkins master is an EC2 instance. I have configured LDAP user login. However, everytime I re-start my ec2 instance I am unable to login with my LDAP user.

Each time I have to go to JENKINS_HOME>config.xml and change < useSecurity >true< /useSecurity> to < useSecurity>false< /useSecurity> and re-start the Jenkins service.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: we can't guess why it happens, until you provide more info, logs, security configs, especially field "Authorization"

Comment: Hi @hopetds ,
I just want to know if rebooting my Jenkins Master(ec2 instance) changes my  LDAP Security settings on Jenkins master.
Authorization field is : Logged-in users can do anything

Comment: @hopetds have attached a screenshot. Please check. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: rebooting doesn't change any settings in jenkins, i suggest you to check jenkins logs/access logs after instance restart. Just to make clear: you are able to login and work properly after you've configured ldap-security auth?

Comment: Yes, I'm able to work properly after configuring ldap settings. The problem is if I'm not using Jenkins, I shut down the EC2 instance to save cost when the machine is idle. Jenkins is not accepting my ldap credentials after I restart the master instance. It gives Invalid login error. So, I change "use Security" to false in order to login. This makes me loose my Ldap settings and I have to reconfigure.
I will check the access logs as suggested by you to find out what the problem is.